# Primefaces Datatable filterOption in columns

Tags: jpa, primefaces, datatable, ejb, filtering

I have a database table displayed through Datatable (Primefaces 3.4.2) and I want to show a comboFilter in the header populated with values from the database table itself.

1) Since these values are not a PK or FK, I built a named query to retrieve distinct values for the prefDep column:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Upb.findPrefDeps", query = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM Upb u WHERE u.prefDep = :prefDep")
```

2) In my AbstractController:

```
public List<T> getPrefDepsList() {
  if (prefDeps == null) {
    prefDeps = this.ejbFacade.findPrefDeps();
    }
      return prefDeps;
}
```

3) As I inject the facade EJB, how can I build a managed bean property to be used in the filterOption below?
The managedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "upbController")
@ViewScoped
public class UpbController extends AbstractController<Upb> implements Serializable {

@EJB
private UpbFacade ejbFacade;

public UpbController() {
    super(Upb.class);
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    super.setFacade(ejbFacade);
}

public SelectItem[] getPrefDepOptions() {
    return prefDepOptions; //build/populate this
 } 
}
```

The jsf:

```
<p:column filterBy="prefdep" headerText="PrefDep"
    filterOptions="#{upbController.prefDepOptions}"  
    filterMatchMode="exact">  
      <h:outputText value="#{item.prefDep}" />  
</p:column>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if I understand your question the right way. You want to execute the named query once and store the distinct values in a property in the managed bean? For that you can use a PreRenderView event which would be called before rendering the page. You can call a init-function to load such values with this event.

You can also access the getter with the named query, but this may be called not only once.

Comment: For better understanding, see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf As you can see in tableBeans.java of the example, the values loaded in the combo are hard coded. Imagine a table where those combo option values changes over time. This is a very hard-boiled way out. Ok, If am I clear now, do you have any idea on how to do it in a non hard-coded fashioned way? And, can you please, provide an example (based on my problem here, if possible) about your idea (_access the getter with the named query_)? I think that's a very good idea, by the way.  Thanks.

Comment: I would do it like that: Make an event on preRenderView or postAddToView (last one isn't called at postback) and fill your values from the named query into a private member to avoid loading them too often from the database.

Then you just have to make a method like `public List<SelectItem> getPrefDepOptions()` in your bean (you can also use own objects in this list!) to give them to the filterOptions attribute as shown in the example. If you have static objects or a dynamic list - primefaces does not care about that. The SelectItems should contain label and value - or you use your own objects.

Comment: anm, do you have any practical example (a link, a book, whatever) about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: I have an example at work, we use cached SelectItems there. But where's the problem? Just take the example from the showcase on the primefaces page and change the getter. The only thing you must do is returning a List of (for example) SelectItems. Your can do the query and fill your result into SelectItems, put them into a List and return them!